# What is this aircraft with a big gun on its back?

Tags: aircraft-design, aircraft-identification

It looks like there is a really big gun on the back of this aircraft.

[image: crazy]
https://www.instagram.com/p/BQVqnYCAlZU/

I found it on Instagram. What is this?

Comment: [The "big gun" is a rocket engine.](http://www.harmjschoonhoven.com/V15_files/V1.jpg)

Comment: @Simon, it definitely is *not* a *rocket* engine; this engine is air-breathing (pulse jet).

Comment: Looking at the better quality picture in ymb1's answer, it looks more like a scope to me...

Comment: @JanHudec Cough, cough, er, that's what I meant. ;) Was thinking of V2, which of course looks nothing like this.  I'll get my coat.

Comment: [The "rocket engine"  is a Pulse-Jet engine](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pulsejet)     @JanHudec You beat me to it, but I am leaving the comment anyway, as a same format counter to Simon's comment

Comment: Now, if you want an aircraft with a big gun, I suggest the [Hs-129 B-3](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Henschel_Hs_129#Hs_129_B-3)

Answer (score 46, accepted):

That's a German WWII [V-1 flying bomb](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/V-1_flying_bomb).

> It was an early cruise missile and the first production aircraft to use a pulsejet for power.

The pulsejet being the tube on top.

[image]
([Source](http://www.aviation-central.com/space/images/usm1d-st.jpg))

Comment: The Germans used to launch these across the English Channel and the brits would defend against them by shooting them down with spitfires.

Comment: Or by tipping them over with wing-to-wing _near_ contact!  Thanks, ymb1, I've spent the last 3 hours reading up on the V-1, V-2 and various other German inventions. It was a nice way to pass a Friday afternoon...

Comment: @FreeMan And by AA guns controlled by trajectory-predicting control systems. Check out this lecture [Between Human And Machine: Feedback, Control and Computing Before Cybernetics](http://techtv.mit.edu/videos/15829-between-human-and-machine-feedback-control-and-computing-before-cybernetics) at 00:43